# High-rep user making useless edit just to be able to downvote

Tags: discussion, voting, privileges

I've just noticed the following unusual voting behavior on [an old answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230138/sql-server-make-all-upper-case-to-proper-case-title-case/230224#230224):

[image: unupvote + downvote]

So apparently someone was unhappy with his upvote and reversed it. But - there was no upvote on this answer for a very long time and you lose the ability for vote reversal after a couple of minutes.

So it's not much of a surprise, in parallel the user did this:

[image: useless edit]

No comment, no explanation, just the undue reversal of an age-old upvote.

In other words, user [Brian Webster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/127880) used his capabilities of doing unchecked edits to allow himself to abuse the voting system.

Is this acceptable behavior?

Comment: Certainly unsavory, but I'm not sure if that consitutes abuse. I'd love to hear from a mod on this, though. It may be worth not directly mentioning and shaming the user, though. We really don't need a meta witchhunt on that to determine whether or not the behavior is bad.

Comment: Well, anyone who clicks on the edit can see how it went down, so the whole thing is public either way. (And yes, using extended capabilities to scratch an itch you just had constitutes abuse. What else would you call that?`)

Comment: It's really not worth getting het up over one vote, especially as you don't know it was Brian. Anyone else who previously voted could have taken advantage of the question being edited to change their vote.

Comment: Robert - no. You can't reverse old votes. Try it. The timing is just too close and the edit is just too meaningless.

Comment: The consensus so far has always been that this is indeed acceptable behaviour.

Comment: I upvoted that answer, if it's any consolation, but I hardly consider one specific case as abuse of the voting system

Comment: @Alon Thanks, but I can candle -12 rep at this point. :)

Comment: 12 rep is 0,00541% of your rep, you're gonna be fine :3

Comment: Posting on meta is also an "extended capability", one that you're using to call or another user. Please stop the abuse! What else would you call that? Seriously though, you have more than enough rep to absorb a 12 point loss, and can revert the edit. Move on.

Comment: @Pekka That makes no sense. In a situation where you have been given extended powers by a community you can't start to use them for personal gain (i.e. "I don't care, I want to do this now!"). This is definitely not acceptable behavior in my book. Think police officers. They can't simply go around and shoot people just because they have a fire... oh, never mind.

Comment: @davidism Nonsense. See second comment above: "Well, anyone who clicks on the edit can see how it went down, so the whole thing is public either way." I'm not "calling on" anybody. I ask whether we should tolerate that mods use permissions they have been entrusted with for their personal whims.

Comment: They're not a mod. And I did see your comment, that's what mine was riffing on.

Comment: @davidism Oh come on, talk about the argument, not about my wording.

Comment: Nobody complains when a user edits to be able to switch their downvote to an upvote... I can see how it's more annoying when it's the other way around, but that doesn't make it any less acceptable as far as how the site works goes. (Mind you, I personally always feel like "just make a trivial edit" guidance is kinda lame... but the alternative of "flip flop between votes as often as you want" seems worse.)

Comment: (To be clear - I don't know if the same user made the edit and the downvote in this case. I haven't looked since it's fairly irrelevant to the core of the post here.)

Comment: @Adam *"Nobody complains when a user edits to be able to switch their downvote to an upvote"* Fair point. Of course the reason is that upvotes (and especially in the form of undone downvotes) are overall perceived as benevolent. Making edits just to be able do them is not all-right, either, though.

Comment: Perhaps the upvote was accidental - I know it's rather easy to do that, on a mobile, e.g - and they hadn't even looked at your post originally. Now that they've come across your answer again, fully digested it, and figured that it deserves a downvote, should they not be able to do that because of an accident a while ago? I'd say this isn't really a problem, if it's a one-off.

Comment: @Mike I don't think edits like this one are accidental. I'm not talking about some person downvoting my post, it would be a bit much to open a meta post for that. ;)

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following ya. I agree the _edit_ was intentional, because their previous vote was locked in. I mean, what if they didn't intend to vote on your post at all, way back when, and having come across it now, thinks it deserves a downvote. The only recourse is an edit, since the previous accidental upvote is locked. It's a bit drastic, I'll give ya that, but there is no confirmation dialog, or the like, for votes, so I guess my point is, if it was an accidental upvote originally, is this really abuse of the system, or possibly just a workaround for a failing therein?

Comment: Again, I don't think it's a problem, until it becomes a problem; i.e., until they continue to do this, to blatantly abuse it. Just my 2¢. :)

Comment: @MikeM. *"what if they didn't intend to vote on your post at all, way back when, and having come across it now, thinks it deserves a downvote"* - well, tough luck. Thought experiment: A low-rep user feels the sudden urge to reverse a half-year old upvote of his. He can't, because it's locked. But he knows an high-rep user and asks him to do a meaningless edit, so he may reverse his vote. The high-rep user does it on the grounds that they are buddies. Would that be be abuse, or would it okay? Why is it okay when no low-rep user is involved?

Comment: @ben75 The answer to the question you made this a duplicate of rightfully points out that a meaningless edit would probably be rejected by the community. My question is about the situation where user *circumvents* this check to satisfy his personal urges (that he could have let go just as well - I don't see why I would have to let something go here)

Comment: Looking at Brian Webster's reputation (http://stackoverflow.com/users/127880/brian-webster?tab=reputation), you can see that he has no recent downvotes, and certainly nothing for the answer at hand.  It's very likely that the downvote came randomly from someone watching the "active" queue, since this question would have suddenly become active again after the edit.

Comment: Do focus a bit on the real problem, the vote lock-in feature is a very silly one.  Pretty bizarre that you can't change a vote when a practice becomes outdated or a superior solution is found.  I wasn't quite around for it but this decision dates back to the early years, back when there were lots of gun-slingers around and "strategic voting" got lots of users upset.  Not a problem at all today.  Maybe because vote lock-in worked so well, who knows.  Consider proposing for the feature to be removed.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill I'm not sure that the reputation tab shows downvotes you made - it shows only downvotes you received.

Comment: @HansPassant Hm. I'm quite content with the vote lock feature. Strategic voting is no longer a problem because of it, not because people would not do it anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure if this is worth kicking up a fuss over.

It's certainly not very nice, and probably a little petty to do, but is it really worth complaining over?

You lost 12 rep over this, that's around 0,005% of your rep. Your answer is still highly voted, and no greater harm has been done. Generally, users are free to vote as they please. What if the guy had downvoted from the start instead of upvoted?

What if it wasn't even him that changed the vote? It could have been one of the other 50+ voters taking advantage of the edit.

I really don't think this is worth the meta attention, and it's a little unfair to assume it was this user who voted when you can't even verify that. And verifying that would probably be a huge O waste of time for the people who can (CMs).

Comment: Again, I am not complaining about the rep loss. (Why do you think that? I don't even mention it, like, at all.)

Comment: @Tomalak The rep loss is the only tangible effect on this. The standing of the answer changes in no noticeable way. You can revert the edit. Why do you care enough to make a meta post. Not worth it, imo (thats the main part of my answer)

Comment: Imagine if reverting edits also reverted all votes that were cast after that edit was made...

Comment: @Magisch Well, I can only tell you that I could not care less about -12 reputation and I wrote pretty clearly about the point that bugs me about this transaction. I wouldn't even have blinked if it was about a fresh vote, i.e. within the limits of the system. The consensus seems to be that nothing can be done about it and therefore it's okay. I think that's not the way how one arrives at the conclusion that something is okay. ;)